# how to add Places search box and text directions with setPanel() together in javascript, google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to add place search and text directions with setPanel() together. but i couldn't do it.

i want to add this options together.

[setPanel()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel) and [placeSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) together.

I'm new to google map api. can anyone help me?

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }
#type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

//var places;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chennai = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0475604,80.2089535);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    center: chennai
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
 var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
   var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    alert(places);

});
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = places;
  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <input id="pac-input" onchange="calcRoute();" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="panel"></div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your code look like so far?

Comment: @duncan i added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, when you are using google FormElement you don't have to call calcRoute() in the input element.

Just use following code, and it will work.

1) Google form submission:

```
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    calcRoute(places[0].geometry.location);
```

2) calcRoute Function's first parameter:

```
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(places.A,places.F);
```

3) if you want to use setpanel() method, just place this code below directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

this will work.

```
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
```

Comment: what is the places.A,places.F?

Comment: the response from the searchBox.getPlaces() gives an object. You can see that with console.log(places). I just passed the places[0].geometry.location to calcroute function, and use A,F properties

Comment: there is an error in this line   calcRoute(places[0].geometry.location);

Comment: Do not use undocumented properties (places.A, place.F), they will change with new releases of the API and your code will break.  Probably should be replaced with places.lat() and places.lng(), or just use `places` which seems to be a `google.maps.LatLng` object already.